# Shopware 6 Product API limit with offset

Tags: api, rest, shopware, shopware6

When using Shopware 6 /api/product REST-API I do get an timeout.
I found out i can set an limit and an offset.
When I call the API with /api/product?limit=240&offset=240 I still get the first 240 products.
Also tried using Shopware 5 offset variant, where you use start instead of offset.
Both give the same result.
I also tried doing an POST instead of an GET request, also no success.
I even using /api/search/product...

Does anyone know how to correctly perform an offset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the shopware 6 API you can request paginated data by using `limit` and `page` parameters. The `page` roughly translates to the offset that is being used, instead of doing a request with an offset of 240 (as in your example) you would request the `page=2` with a limit of 240 this would give you the results 241-480.

So instead of

```
/api/product?limit=240&offset=240
```

you should use

```
/api/product?limit=240&page=2
```

The `limit` and `page` parameters can be used in GET-Requests, but also in POST-Request in the JSON-Body or in the `search` endpoint.

Take a look at [the official docs](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/integrations-api/general-concepts/search-criteria#page-and-limit) for reference.